# Does Node js have advanced mapping like in Spring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to store a document inside another document, in Spring there are **DBRef** and **DocumentReference** when working with Spring Data MongoDB. I can't find anything similar with Mongoose. What will be the equivalent in Node js? It's like Spring is a heavier backend, and Node js is not that capable.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Mongoose with the nodeJS but there are 2 different ways.

The simplest way is just to use an ObjectId type for the field that contains the next schema but this is suitable for when searching Task by user ID or reverse.

Here is an example

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name        : String,
    })
    
    var TaskSchema = new Schema({
        name            : String,
        user            : Schema.ObjectId
    });

const tasks = await Task.find({user: user_id});
```

Here is a [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) for your reference

---

but there is another way to do that with mongoose populate. Here is an example.

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
});
```

Here is how to save data to the above schema.

```
const author = new Person({
  name: 'Ian Fleming',
});

await author.save();

const story1 = new Story({
  title: 'Casino Royale',
  author: author._id // assign the _id from the person
});

await story1.save();
```

Here is how to fetch author details by giving the story name.

```
const story = await Story.
  findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
  populate('author').
  exec();
// prints "The author is Ian Fleming"
console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
```

Here is a [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) for the populate function.